# file_get_contents returning "File not found"

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

I am trying to fetch the contents of a url but file_get_contents is returning "File not found". This is the code I am using:

```
$url = "https://www.auction.com/residential/CA/active_lt/land_pt/resi_sort_v2_st/y_nbs/";
$context = stream_context_create(array(
    'https' => array(
        'method' => "GET",
        'header' =>
            "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\r\n" .
            "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8\r\n".
            "Keep-Alive: timeout=3, max=10\r\n",
            "Connection: keep-alive",
        'user_agent' => "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.66 Safari/535.11",
        "ignore_errors" => true,
        "timeout" => 3
    )
));
file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```

But it is not working. Can you please help make this work? Or, is there any other method?

Answer (score 0):

Try this its work at my end

```
$ch = curl_init();
$curlConfig = array(
    CURLOPT_URL            => "https://www.auction.com/residential/CA/active_lt/land_pt/resi_sort_v2_st/y_nbs/",
    //CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER     => array('Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\r\n','Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8\r\n','Keep-Alive: timeout=3, max=10\r\n','Connection: keep-alive'),
    CURLOPT_POST           => false,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,

);
curl_setopt_array($ch, $curlConfig);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo'<pre>';print_r($result);
```

Comment: Do or do not. There is no "try". A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: I am still getting the `Page not Found` error, and I have ran the script from 3 different domains. Why would you think it is not working for me? Are you able to fetch the contents of the url and print them in your screen?